# enable_if: minimal example for void member function with no arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, void, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to get a better understanding of `std::enable_if` in C++11 and have been trying to write a minimal example: a class `A` with a member function `void foo()` that has different implementations based on the type `T` from the class template.
The below code gives the desired result, but I am not understanding it fully yet. Why does version `V2` work, but not `V1`? Why is the "redundant" type `U` required?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A {

    public:

        A(T x) : a_(x) {}

        // Enable this function if T == int
        /* V1 */ // template <           typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value,int>::type = 0>
        /* V2 */ template <typename U=T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,int>::value,int>::type = 0>
        void foo() { std::cout << "\nINT: " << a_ << "\n"; }

        // Enable this function if T == double
        template <typename U=T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,double>::value,int>::type = 0>
        void foo() { std::cout << "\nDOUBLE: " << a_ << "\n"; }

    private:

        T a_;

};

int main() {
    A<int> aInt(1); aInt.foo();
    A<double> aDouble(3.14); aDouble.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result, i.e. for having different implementations of a `void foo()` function based on a class template parameter?

Comment: Your example is not an appropriate use of `enable_if`. Simple overloading would solve your case. `enable_if` is mostly useful on a *deduced* template parameter.

Comment: Using `std::enable_if` would be suited for separating deduced *floating point* types from, say, *integral* types. Two specific types like this would be better suited for *overloading*.

Comment: @KerrekSB @WhozCraig How would I overload in this particular case? By using an out-of-class definition `void A<int>::foo() {}` and `void A<double>::foo() {}`? My intention would be that the final code only contains those versions of the function that are required (i.e. no function `A<double>::foo()` if such a function is never called)

Comment: As I understand the question is about why and how the redundant `typename U=T` makes the example work, but not without it. Anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this wont fully answer your question, but it might give you some more ideas and understanding of how you can use `std::enable_if`.

You could replace your foo member functions with the following and have identical functionality:

```
template<typename U=T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,int>::value>::type
foo(){ /* enabled when T is type int */ }

template<typename U=T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,double>::value>::type
foo(){ /* enabled when T is type double */ }
```

A while back I gained a pretty good understanding of how enable_if works, but sadly I have forgotten most of its intricacies and just remember the more practical ways to use it.

Comment: I think you need to also remove the `void` before the function since it is now already included in the `std::enable_if<>`. But thx for this input, helped me to get one step closer to understanding what is going on. Would you say this is a legit way of achieving compile-time polymorphism?

Comment: @untergam Whoops, nice catch! I'll edit that now. I think it is a legit way of doing thing, I'm just not sure if there's better ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question: why V1 doesn't work? SFINAE applies only in overload resolution - V1 however causes error at the point where type A is instantiated, well before `foo()` overload resolution.

I suppose there are lot's of possible implementations - which is the most appropriate depends on an actual case in question. A common approach would be to defer the part of `A` that's different for different template types to a helper class.

```
template <typename T>
class A_Helper;

template <>
class A_Helper<int> {
public:
    static void foo( int value ){
        std::cout << "INT: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
class A_Helper<double> {
public:
    static void foo( double value ){
        std::cout << "DOUBLE: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class A {
public:

    A( T a ) : a_(a) 
    {}

    void foo(){
        A_Helper<T>::foo(a_);
    }

private:
    T a_;
};
```

The rest of `A` can be declared only once in a generic way - only the parts that differ are deferred to a helper. There is a lot of possible variations on that - depending on your requirements...

Comment: Thanks @j_kubik for your answer. I see how this solution with templated helper classes would work, but this is exactly the kind of code-bloating that I was trying to avoid in the first place. I would prefer a minimal version with `enable_if` or at least with similarly short syntax.