# How to enable member function using boolean template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like a class to have two different implementations of `push`, and choose based on a boolean template argument. I tried using the SFINAE principle as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740466/6263317), like so:

```
template<class T, bool foo=true>
class Bar {
  template <>
  typename std::enable_if<foo>::type
  push(const T& value) { /* one implementation */}

  template <>
  typename std::enable_if<!foo>::type
  push(const T& value) { /* another implementation */ } 
}
```

however, I am getting an error of "cannot specialize a function `push` within class scope" under gcc, and I do not understand why. Although my code is not exactly like that in the linked answer, it seems very similar and I can't spot the critical difference.

I also tried using a syntax similar to that suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001963/6263317) but it is also not working (the error is "class member cannot be redeclared" instead):

```
  template <bool enable=foo>
  typename std::enable_if<enable>::type
  push(const T& value) { /* one implementation */}

  template <bool enable=!foo>
  typename std::enable_if<enable>::type
  push(const T& value) { /* another implementation */ }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) works with function templates overloading; so you should go with the 2nd approach. But you declare two overloads with same signature; note that the default argument of template parameter doesn't belong to the signature.

Change it to

```
template <bool enable=foo>
typename std::enable_if<enable>::type
//                      ~~~~~~
push(const T& value) { /* one implementation */}

template <bool enable=foo>
typename std::enable_if<!enable>::type
//                      ~~~~~~~
push(const T& value) { /* another implementation */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

As alternatives:

- `if constexpr` in C++17:

  ```
  template<class T, bool foo=true>
  class Bar {
  public:
      void push(const T& value) {
          if constexpr(foo) {
              /* one implementation */
          } else {
              /* another implementation */
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- Tag dispatching:

  ```
  template<class T, bool foo=true>
  class Bar {
      void push_impl(const T& value, std::true_type) {
          /* one implementation */
      } 
      void push_impl(const T& value, std::false_type) {
          /* another implementation */
      }

  public:
      void push(const T& value) {
          push_impl(value, std::integral_constant<bool, foo>{});
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the alternate options. I'm sure I will find these useful at some point.